# The notification is shown on the emulator, but when the application is launched on a real phone (Xiaomi redmi note 7), the notification is not shown

Tags: android, notifications, xiaomi

The notification is shown on the emulator, but when the application is launched on a real phone (Xiaomi redmi note 7), the notification is not shown.

I have tested emulators with api 23, 30.

```
companion object {
    const val channelName = "channel name for app, test"
    const val channelID = "channel id 1, test"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var notificationId = 0

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
        )
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
            .notify(notificationId, builder.build())
        notificationId++
    }
}


private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val important = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, important)
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Go To App Info > Check if Show Notifications is On

Comment: @AyushSaini, i checked notifications are on

Comment: Have you called createNotificationChannel() to create channel?

Comment: @AyushSaini ohh, thank you it was really my problem